# How to serialize and deserialize the XML in spring boot?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have an XML request and the response of media type TEXT/XML.

I am trying to serialize and deserialize the request and response in spring boot.

Request body as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ws="http://ws">
   <soapenv:Header />
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:doKF>
         <parameterIn><![CDATA[<KFWS>
  <RqUID>0f73a59f-8388-492e-b17d-ba1fb1b1d2fd</RqUID>
  <ClientApp>A</ClientApp>
  <SignOn>
    <Username>web</Username>
    <Password>Web@123</Password>
  </SignOn>
  <CaListOfflineRq>
    <CR>123456</CR>
  </CaListOfflineRq>
</KFWS>]]></parameterIn>
      </ws:doKF>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response as follows

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
           <NS1:Body>
              <NS2:doKFResponse xmlns:NS2="http://ws">
                 <NS2:parameterOut>
                    <KFWS>
                       <RqUID>0f73a59f-8388-492e-b17d-ba1fb1b1d2fd</RqUID>
                       <LogID>48151382-77bc-11eb-8dbc-0a05010a0000</LogID>
                       <Status>
                          <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
                          <StatusDesc>Success</StatusDesc>
                       </Status>
                       <CaListOfflineRs>
                          <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
                          <ReturnDesc>Success</ReturnDesc>
                          <CaCards>
                             <CaCard>
                                <CaMasked>490061</CaMasked>
                                <CaNoToken>2140</CaNoToken>
                                <CaToken>2140</CaToken>
                                <Name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Name>
                                <Type>Primary</Type>
                                <Class>SMART</Class>
                                <Status>Expired</Status>
                                <Number>20000</Number>
                             </CaCard>
                             <CaCard>
                                <CaMasked>4904061</CaMasked>
                                <CaNoToken>2140</CaNoToken>
                                <CaToken>2140</CaToken>
                                <Name>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</Name>
                                <Type>Primary</Type>
                                <Class>SMART</Class>
                                <Status>Expired</Status>
                                <Number>20000</Number>
                             </CaCard>
                          </CaCards>
                       </CaListOfflineRs>
                    </KFWS>
                 </NS2:parameterOut>
              </NS2:doKFResponse>
           </NS1:Body>
        </NS1:Envelope>
```

I got the response using the Feign client in the string and I need to de-serialise the response to the JSON

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? What have you tried so far? The standard approach is to create data objects that represent your XML structure.

Comment: I need to know how to create the data objects that represent our XML structure

Comment: Actually your main problem is to convert XML into Java pojo classes without having WSDL of that webservice

Comment: yes @Naman jain

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's SOAP response.

See [Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) that shows how to consume such service.

Comment: We don't have WSDL for the above one

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson to serialize and deserialize your xml. You need to look at your xml structure and create the proper POJOs. Here you can find how to do the serialization/deserialization https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization